# Index in Python list contains multiple elements. How to access each and pass them to different function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a code in Python 3 that extracts values from a table(.csv) using pandas and appends them to a list. My code is:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import csv
import pandas as pd
from generate_xml import write_xml

# global constants
img = None
tl_list = []
br_list = []
object_list = []
tl_x = []
tl_y = []
br_x =[]
br_y =[]


# constants
obj = 'red_hat'

df = pd.read_csv('ring_1_05_sam.csv')
tl_x = df.iloc[5:10, 0:1] - 30
tl_y = df.iloc[5:10, 1:2] - 30
br_x = df.iloc[5:10, 0:1] + 30
br_y = df.iloc[5:10, 1:2] + 30
tl_x = (tl_x.to_string(index=False, header=False))
tl_y = (tl_y.to_string(index=False, header=False))
br_x = (br_x.to_string(index=False, header=False))
br_y = (br_y.to_string(index=False, header=False))
tl_list = (tl_x, tl_y)
br_list = (br_x, br_y)
object_list.append(obj)

print(tl_list[0])
```

This gives me an output of

```
1507.50
1507.44
1507.09
1507.00
```

So as you can see, my index[0] at tl_list[] has these 4 elements. My question is how do i access them individually?  To be more specific, I want to pass each value to a function, one at a time

```
import os
import numpy as np
import csv
import pandas as pd
from generate_xml import write_xml

# global constants
img = None
tl_list = []
br_list = []
object_list = []
tl_x = []
tl_y = []
br_x =[]
br_y =[]


# constants
obj = 'red_hat'

df = pd.read_csv('ring_1_05_sam.csv')
tl_x = df.iloc[5:10, 0:1] - 30
tl_y = df.iloc[5:10, 1:2] - 30
br_x = df.iloc[5:10, 0:1] + 30
br_y = df.iloc[5:10, 1:2] + 30
tl_x = (tl_x.to_string(index=False, header=False))
tl_y = (tl_y.to_string(index=False, header=False))
br_x = (br_x.to_string(index=False, header=False))
br_y = (br_y.to_string(index=False, header=False))
tl_list = (tl_x, tl_y)
br_list = (br_x, br_y)
object_list.append(obj)

write_xml(image_folder, img, object_list, tl_list, br_list, savedir)
tl_list = []
br_list = []
object_list = []
img = None
```

So that my write_xml function takes the first value at tl_list and br_list then the next value sequentially. Right now it tales all values at once. Any ideas how i can do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can `split` the string and iterate through the resulting list:

```
for tl in tl_list[0].split():
    write_xml(image_folder, img, object_list, tl, br_list, savedir)
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out as soon as i have time and let you know if it works

Comment: i get this error when i try to run the code  
 for tl in tl_list[0].split():
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: I think you must missed the `[0]` part.

Comment: This is the input i gave 
for tl in tl_list[0].split():
        write_xml(image_folder, img, object_list, tl, br_list, savedir)

Comment: Well in that case `tl_list[0]` is not a string but a tuple. Try `tl_list[0][0].split()` then.